# How to update launch configuration for existing autoscaling group in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to update an existing AWS autoscaling group (which is already created manually long back) with new Launch configuration using terraform.

```
provider "aws" {
access_key = <Access_key>
secret_key = <Secret_key>
region     = <REGION>

data "aws_autoscaling_groups" "asgpoc" {
 filter {
  name = "key"
  values = ["Name"]
 }

 filter {
  name = "value"
  values = ["asgpoc"]
 }
}
output "asgname" {
 value = "${data.aws_autoscaling_groups.asgpoc.names}"
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "tf-dl-poc-asg" {
 availability_zones        = ["us-west-2"]
 name                      = "${data.aws_autoscaling_groups.asgpoc.names[0]}"
 max_size                  = 2
 min_size                  = 1
 health_check_grace_period = 300
 health_check_type         = "EC2"
 desired_capacity          = 1
 force_delete              = false
 launch_configuration      = "tf_dl_asg_lc"
}
```

when I do terraform apply, I am getting error,

> aws_autoscaling_group.tf-dl-poc-asg: Error creating AutoScaling Group:
>   AlreadyExists: AutoScalingGroup by this name already exists - A group
>   with the name asgpoc already exists   status code: 400,
>   request id: ba011d22-2624-s1ea-ace8-fbc37028ec9c

How to solve this issue? Is there any alternate way to update existing AWS ASG with terraform?

Answer (score 1):

The resource you include with `data "aws_autoscaling_groups" "asgpoc"` is not under control by terraform.

You should import the exist resource first.

```
terraform import aws_autoscaling_group.tf-dl-poc-asg asgpoc
```

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you.

Comment: @BMW Any idea why I would get a `Can't import aws_autoscaling_group.proxy, would collide with an existing resource.` when using this?